# Spotfire user dashboard

Tags: spotfire, spotfire-analyst

I am trying to generate a dashboard to display number of users vs dashboards user accessed. Checked user table and can see the last login details of the user.

Comment: Please add your current code, and your research effort.

Comment: SELECT LibraryID, librarypath, USER_NAME, COUNT(DISTINCT USER_NAME) AS UserCount
FROM ANALYSIS_PRO_SET_PAGE
GROUP BY LibraryID,librarypath,USER_NAME

Comment: Not sure which datatable to use